# Can a node.processTemplate ftl use the include command?

Tags: javascript, freemarker, alfresco

I am trying to use a simple **<#include "anotherFile.ftl"/>** inside of a freemarker template that is being processed using the Javascript API's method proccessTemplate (http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/4.0_JavaScript_API#Transformation_API) against a particular node.

It doesn't seem to like includes?!

The error message is as follows

> Wrapped Exception (with status template): 04305890 Failed to execute
>   script
>   'classpath*:alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts/myPath/myWebscript.get.js':
>   04305889 Error during processing of the template 'Error reading
>   included file string://fooy/foo.ftl'. Please contact your system
>   administrator.

The template that is being processed and the potential one to be included will be stored outside of Alfresco's repository, but for now it's inside there.
The webscripts will also be outside of the repository and inside a Java class path.

I have tried to include the ftl even if it's inside the same directory, and this doesn't work.  I have tried to get a node.nodeRef (with success) but the actual include does not work, though this would mean storing the ftl in the repository which we will not be doing anyway.

I did try to include the ftl on the actual webscripts freemarker itself but of course the node.processTemplate happens in the javascript controller before it gets passed to the webscript freemarker template

I even tried to hardcode the contents of the include and pass it in the args associative array, and as expected it didn't work.

Further investigation suggests this is a bug
https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALFCOM-3364

Any other suggestions welcome if anyone has overcome this.

Thanks

Comment: What's the error message? Anyway, I don't know Alfresco, only FreeMarker. FreeMarker has a configuration setting called `templateLoader`, which is the object that implements `freemarker.cache.TemplateLoader` and resolves the absolute paths (like, if you are in `/foo/bar.ftl`, then it will get `/foo/anotherFile.ftl` for that include). So the question is if what implementation does Alfresco use. Looking into that you might understand what's available and with what path.

Comment: What is your scenario, I'm still confused when this template is beeing processed. Is this at an email? Explorer Template?

Comment: @ddekany - I've added an instance of the error and I was pointed out this is a known issue.

Comment: @Tahir - We have a webscript that we're using to process templates on demand for building HTML content stored in Alfresco's repository, these are for web pages.  The webscript is passed a parameters to determine page and template.  Because we want to re-use freemarker macros across the templates we want to include a header file to each freemarker.  Thank you both for responding.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a webscript, then I guess your path isn't right.

E.g.: I've got a webscript foo. It will be present in `alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts/org/test/`
So I'll have foo.get.desc.xml, foo.get.js and foo.get.html.ftl.

I have a common freemarker template in alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts/org/common/common.ftl

Then I'll need to put the `<#include "/org/common/common.ftl" />` in the foo.get.html.ftl freemarker.

So you need to set the path from `alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts`

Comment: Thank for you answer, the include works perfectly fine on the main webscript though this is not where we're trying to include.  Somewhere in the foo.get.js we are grabbing a node and using node.processTemplate with another freemarker as the parameter that is also picked up in the foo.get.js.  The problem is this secondary freemarker does not seem to allow includes.  On my original post I posted a link to Aflresco's Jira stating it's a known bug

Comment: Now it's getting clear sorry. I also had the same issue once but gave up, because you'd need to rewrite the ScriptNode java class